# How to make sure a function only runs once at a time in RxJS pipe?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I made a queue in RxJS. Inside the pipe, there is a function `title`:

```js
const title$ = titleTasks$.pipe(
  groupBy(({ title }) => title),
  mergeMap((group$) =>
    group$.pipe(
      concatMap((task) =>
        defer(() => from(title(task))).pipe(
          map(() => ({
            success: true,
            error: undefined,
            ...task,
          })),
          catchError((error) => of({ success: false, error, ...task })),
          tap((taskResult) => {
            taskResult$.next(taskResult);
          }),
          switchMap((taskResult) =>
            race(
              timer(taskResult.success ? task.ttl * 1000 : 0),
              cancelTitleTimer$
            ).pipe(switchMap(() => of(taskResult)))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```

I want to make sure this function only runs once at a time. It can run again after `race` finished at the end. I made this [playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-u3cbhw?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts) to demonstrate how the function currently runs without waiting for the previous `race`.

I tried to use a shared queue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3f3c1r?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you're trying to achieve by splitting the tasks by title to then process every item like a single pipeline, but you can do it:

- replacing the `concatMap` in the group$ with a sigle `map` to return an Observable of Observables.
- and then adding the operator `concatAll` in the main pipe to process each of these Observables one by one.

  ```
  const title$ = titleTasks$.pipe(
    groupBy(({ title }) => title),
    mergeMap((group$) =>
      group$.pipe(
        map((task) =>  //<--- replaced concatMap with map
           defer(...)
        )
      ) 
    ),
    concatAll(), // <-- added to process the inner observables returned 1 by 1
  )
  ```

cheers

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to help out with [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77659873/observable-not-running-in-rxjs-concat)?