# Observable not running in RxJS concat

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have 3 functions

```js
async function startTask() {
  console.log('starting task');

  await wait(1000);

  return true;
}

async function fetchScan(options: Extract<Task, { type: TaskType.SCAN }>) {
  console.log('starting scan');

  return startTask();
}

async function fetchTitle(options: Extract<Task, { type: TaskType.TITLE }>) {
  console.log('starting title');

  return startTask();
}
```

The functions at the bottom make use of `startTask` which can only run once at a time. `fetchTitle` accepts different titles. Each are kept for some time until the time runs out. A different title does not have to wait that time. I made this queue in RxJS which queues tasks for both fetch functions, trying to ensure that `startTask` only runs once at a time:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qnoga4?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

```js
concat(title$, scan$).subscribe((taskResult) => {
  if (taskResult.success) {
    return taskResult.logger(`Successfully finished: ${taskResult.type}.`);
  }

  taskResult.logger(`Failed ${taskResult.type}. ${taskResult.error}`);
});
```

The problem is that the titles run at the same time and scan does not seem to run at all. The expected output is

```
starting title
starting task
1, { success: true...

starting title
starting task
2, { success: true...

starting scan
starting task
3, { success: true...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is pretty much the same as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77641088/how-to-make-sure-a-function-only-runs-once-at-a-time-in-rxjs-pipe).

So the solution is again to return an Observable of Observables from both `title$` and `scan$` and then `merge` both into a single pipeline and use `concatAll` to process each of the emitted Observables one by one.

```
const title$ = titleTasks$.pipe(
  groupBy(({ title }) => title),
  mergeMap((group$) =>
     group$.pipe(
      map((task) =>  //<--- replaced concatMap with map
       defer(...)
      )
    ) 
  )
);  

const scan$ = scanTasks$.pipe(
  map((task) =>  //<--- replaced concatMap with map
    defer(() => ...)
  )
);

merge(title$, scan$).pipe( //<--- replaced concat with merge
  concatAll() //<-- add concatAll to process emitted Obs  1 by 1
).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: There seems to be a small issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-o7twzj?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts, userId 2 is waiting for 12 but it shouldn't have to because it's a different title from userId 1, I think concatAll isn't what I'm after here. Users requesting the same title only have to wait for the previous title timeout to finish, but everyone has to wait for the title and scan methods

Comment: @Dan what would be the expected output then? Cause by looking at the expected output you added in the question, one can assume that no task can start before the previous has completed.

Comment: The desired output is showing here without using map instead of mergeMap: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kams1r?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts wonder if it's possible to achieve this in a way scan$ still runs

Comment: @Dan if scan$ can run parallel to the titles, you could do `merge(title$, scan$).subscribe(...)`

Comment: It actually seems fine, thanks